# how to remove duplicated results of date in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
ID DATE   
1  2006-01-01  
1  2007-01-01   
2  2008-01-02   
2  2007-01-02   
2  2012-01-03   
2  2011-02-20
```

The rule is to count number of dates of different ID in Jan, where duplicated date shouldn't be counted twice. (date in DATE format)

The output should like this:

```
ID num_date   
1   1   
2   2
```

I tried DUPLICATE but it doesn't work I have no idea how to ignore the annoying year, can anyone help?

Comment: JOin on a COUNT DISTINCT query WHERE month=jan .Also what is your database,dont tag random databases

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Different DBMS's have different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT id, count(*) AS num_date
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT id, date
  FROM my_table
  WHERE extract(month from date) = 1) sub
GROUP BY id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select
   f.id,
    count(f.id) from (
        select d.id,count(date_format(d.date,'%d')) dat from your_table d
            where date_format(date,'%mm') = 01
            group by id, date_format(date,'%m%d')
        ) f
group by f.id
```

Answer (score -1):

may be you can do that without join, if you are use sql. try this for january I use 01

For PostgreSQL

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct DATE_PART('DAY', DATE)) 
       FROM[tableName] 
       WHERE DATE_PART('MONTH', DATE)=01 
       GROUP BY ID, DATE_PART('MONTH', DATE)
```

For MS-SQL

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct DATEPART(DAY, DATE)) 
       FROM[tableName] 
       WHERE DATEPART(MONTH, DATE)=01
       GROUP BY ID, DATEPART(MONTH, DATE)
```

Comment: OP is about PostgreSQL, as he commented after your answer

Comment: Thank you. I used PostgreSQL, and the above command can be edited as follows and now works:                                                                                                           SELECT ID, COUNT(distinct DATE_PART('DAY', DATE)) 
       FROM[tableName] 
       WHERE DATE_PART('MONTH', DATE)=01
       GROUP BY ID, DATE_PART('MONTH', DATE)

Comment: @JackYe I add your query as I don't know PostgreSQL.

Comment: I don't know why I got negative vote. Can you please describe about my wrong.